# mysql query optimization - join and orderby

Tags: sql, mysql

I need a little help by one mysql query optimization. It is a simple query but anything is not right and I can't found it :-(

I have 2 tables: products (> 40000 Rows) and product_tags (> 5 mil)

There is a relation betweet the tables 1 -> N . Every prdoduct can have many tags in the table product tags.

I have this simple Query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT t.product_id, kwt.tag_id
FROM products AS t, product_tags AS kwt
WHERE 1
AND t.product_id = kwt.product_id
AND kwt.tag_id =11
ORDER BY t.order_date
```

wchich returns 55 results.

First Situation: if I have this table structure of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `product_source_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `order_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`product_id`),
  KEY `order_date` (`order_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_tags` (
  `product_tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`product_tag_id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  ;
```

Then the Explain of the query is this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                       | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | index | PRIMARY       | order_date | 4       | NULL                      | 45392 | Using index | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | kwt   | ref   | product_id    | product_id | 4       | t.product_id          |     3 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

It is getting all the rows from table products, but there is nothing with temporary table.

Second Situation: If I add an index for the field "tag_id" in product_tags, then the picture is different:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | kwt   | ref    | product_id,tag_id | tag_id  | 4       | const                       |   55 | Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY | 4       | kwt.product_id              |    1 | Using where                     | 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Now it selects only 55 rows, what is right, but the query is havy :(

Where is my mistake here ?

Thanks
Nik

Comment: And do not ever use implied joins again, they are a poor programming techinique that is almost 20 years out of date. For shame that you are writing code in 2011 using this syntax. learn to use explixit joins.

Answer (score 1):

this is what i would do:

### Read these resources

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html
- http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/04/how-to-exploit-mysql-index-optimizations/

### Redesign your system to take advantage of a clustered primary key

**Simplified schema:**

```
drop table if exists products;
create table products
(
prod_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(255) not null unique
)
engine = innodb; 

drop table if exists tags;
create table tags
(
tag_id mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(255) not null unique
)
engine = innodb; 

drop table if exists product_tags;
create table product_tags
(
tag_id mediumint unsigned not null,
prod_id int unsigned not null,
created_date date not null,
primary key (tag_id, prod_id), -- note the clustered composite index and the order !!
key (prod_id)
)
engine = innodb;
```

### Test the schema

```
select
 pt.tag_id,
 pt.prod_id
from
 product_tags pt
inner join products p on pt.prod_id = p.prod_id
where
 pt.tag_id = 11
order by
 pt.created_date
limit 10;
```

I may even change the product_tags PK to primary key (tag_id, prod_id, created_date) but it all depends on the typical queries you run. You could ofc, just create a non clustered secondary index on created date if you think that's gonna boost performance.

Hope this helps :)